# how to convert datatable to list<string> and then compare it with a Textbox value?

Tags: c#, list, datatable

I have a DataTable -> "**CheckProduct(String id)**"  **where String ID is invoice id which is used fetch product ids of that invoice**

**Now i want to compare it with a Textbox value.**

I have tried a code for it.

**My Datalogic :-**

```
 public DataTable CheckProduct(String id)
        {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlConnection sqlconnection;
                sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(@" Database Connection String");
                sqlconnection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("checkproduct", sqlconnection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@inv_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = int.Parse(id);
                DataSet dtset = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adpt.Fill(dtset);
                dt = dtset.Tables[0];

                return dt;
        }
```

> **My Business logic :-**

```
  public List<String> CheckProduct(String id)
        {    
                SPDatalogic sp = new SPDatalogic(); //datalogic class
                DataTable dt = new DataTable() ;
                dt = sp.CheckProduct(id);
                List<String> list = new List<String>();                     
                SPBusinesslogic ab = new SPBusinesslogic();  //businesslogic class
                String pro;
                pro =ab.CheckProduct(id).ToString();
                list.Add(pro);    

                return list;

        }
```

> **My Presentation Layer:-**

```
            string id = invoice_no_textbox.Text;
            SPBusinesslogic ab = new SPBusinesslogic(); //businesslogic class
            List<String> id_list = new List<String>();
           id_list = ab.CheckProduct(id);  //passing invoice_no as string id


            if (id_list.Any(x => x.Equals(invoice_no_textbox.Text)))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("the product already exist");
            }
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Why do you iterating table rows in your business logic, but don't use variable inside cycle?

Comment: @Steve its not working i dont know where i am committing mistake.

Comment: @Uriil its my mistake i tried to first to add datarow to string first
then changed it. omit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that the field name for your invoice id is called "invoice_id" I would rewrite the code of CheckProduct to be

```
public List<String> CheckProduct(String id)
{    
        SPDatalogic sp = new SPDatalogic(); //datalogic class
        DataTable dt = sp.CheckProduct(id);
        List<String> list = new List<String>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            list.Add(dr["invoice_id"].ToString());    
        }
        return list;
}
```

In your code, you call recursively the CheckProduct method passing again the ID of the invoice and doesn't seems to be a way out of that loop. Instead the list of products for the invoice are already known from the previous call to the SPDatalogic class. So you just need to add them to your list

Also in the DataLogic class there is a possible error in the declaration of the parameter.  If @inv_id is of type integer, then don't declare the parameter as VarChar

```
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@inv_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(id);
```

And as a final note, I don't understand why you want to work with a `List<string>` when your IDs are clearly numbers. This causes continue conversions of type from string to int and viceversa. You shoud retrive a `List<int>` and convert just the input of your textbox.

Comment: Thanks it worked.
I did it with list<int> and its working

i have declared @inv_id as int in store procedure so their is no problem